# Possible to solder back detached ribbon cable?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

I have a Yamaha PSR-F51 whose ribbon connector cable snapped off from the PCB, where the leads were soldered to the PCB (see picture below).

Is it possible to solder these back? Or if not, what are they actually called, if it is to be replaced? Is it possible?

I tried exposing the bare cable leads for resoldering, to no avail.

It's one of the cables as pictured below. As you can see they attach to the board, and are soldered to it on the underside.

[image: psrf51 ribbon cable]

Edit: I should've made it clear that the image posted is one I found, not of the actual severed ribbon cable in the question.

Below is the actual severed cable, showing the actual edge with barely any leads exposed for soldering, and googling the cable print for replacement showed nil.

[image: actual cable in question]

Comment: It’s not obvious where it’s broken.  If it’s just one core then you might do well to bypass the break with a length of jumper wire.

Comment: The cables aren't soldered to the board.  The white connectors are.   The cables insert into those connectors and are held tight by friction.  You can easily disconnect them by prying the tabs on the side up.   If you wanna fix this rather than make a mess of it, suggest you find somebody familiar with working on this kind of stuff to do it for you.

Comment: None of the ribbon cables in that picture are broken or disconnected. Please post a picture that shows the broken or disconnected ribbon cable.

Comment: i've uploaded a photo of the severed cable (just thought first 'pic showed cable etc types clearer)..

Comment: Could you also post a photo of the PCB connector the severed cable connected to? If the PCB connector is still on the PCB and in one piece, this could well be repairable (without soldering).